# Cannot insert the value NULL into column does not allow nulls

Tags: sql-server

I have created two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Seller_(
    ID_SELLER INT NOT NULL,
    PASS VARCHAR (8) NULL,
    FIO VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    ADRESS VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_SELLER),
);

CREATE TABLE Zakaz_(
    ID_ZAKAZ INT NOT NULL,
    DATE_ DATE NULL,
    ID_SELLER INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Seller_(ID_SELLER) 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_ZAKAZ)
);
```

I am inserting into these tables like this:

```
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER,PASS,FIO,ADRESS) VALUES (111,'abcd1','Anton','derevnya universiady');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER,PASS,FIO,ADRESS) VALUES (112,'abcd2','Andrey','pushkina');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER,PASS,FIO,ADRESS) VALUES (113,'abcd3','Abdul','krasnaya pozitsiya');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER,PASS,FIO,ADRESS) VALUES (114,'abcd1','Alsu','derevnya universiady');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER,PASS,FIO,ADRESS) VALUES (115,'abcd2','Anna','pushkina');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER,PASS,FIO,ADRESS) VALUES (116,'abcd3','Azamat','krasnaya pozitsiya');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER,PASS,FIO,ADRESS) VALUES (117,'abcd2','Sergei','pushkina');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER,PASS,FIO,ADRESS) VALUES (118,'abcd1','Leysan','derevnya universiady');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER,PASS,FIO,ADRESS) VALUES (119,'abcd1','Katya','derevnya universiady');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER,PASS,FIO,ADRESS) VALUES (120,'abcd3','Anastasia','krasnaya pozitsiya');

INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ,DATE_) VALUES (111,GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ,DATE_) VALUES (112,GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ,DATE_) VALUES (113,GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ,DATE_) VALUES (114,GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ,DATE_) VALUES (115,GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ,DATE_) VALUES (116,GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ,DATE_) VALUES (117,GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ,DATE_) VALUES (118,GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ,DATE_) VALUES (119,GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ,DATE_) VALUES (112,GETDATE());
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 27
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID_SELLER', table 'test.dbo.Zakaz_'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 28
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID_SELLER', table 'test.dbo.Zakaz_'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 29
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID_SELLER', table 'test.dbo.Zakaz_'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
...
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

The ID_SELLER column in the Zakaz_ table must contain a ID for a record in the Seller_ table. That way you can know which Seller_ each Zakaz_ is associated with.

For example, this would work, althought only you can determine the correct values:

```
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER, PASS, FIO, ADRESS) VALUES (111, 'abcd1', 'Anton', 'derevnya universiady');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER, PASS, FIO, ADRESS) VALUES (112, 'abcd2', 'Andrey', 'pushkina');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER, PASS, FIO, ADRESS) VALUES (113, 'abcd3', 'Abdul', 'krasnaya pozitsiya');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER, PASS, FIO, ADRESS) VALUES (114, 'abcd1', 'Alsu', 'derevnya universiady');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER, PASS, FIO, ADRESS) VALUES (115, 'abcd2', 'Anna', 'pushkina');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER, PASS, FIO, ADRESS) VALUES (116, 'abcd3', 'Azamat', 'krasnaya pozitsiya');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER, PASS, FIO, ADRESS) VALUES (117, 'abcd2', 'Sergei', 'pushkina');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER, PASS, FIO, ADRESS) VALUES (118, 'abcd1', 'Leysan', 'derevnya universiady');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER, PASS, FIO, ADRESS) VALUES (119, 'abcd1', 'Katya', 'derevnya universiady');
INSERT INTO Seller_(ID_SELLER, PASS, FIO, ADRESS) VALUES (120, 'abcd3', 'Anastasia', 'krasnaya pozitsiya');

INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ, ID_SELLER, DATE_) VALUES (201, 111, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ, ID_SELLER, DATE_) VALUES (202, 112, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ, ID_SELLER, DATE_) VALUES (203, 113, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ, ID_SELLER, DATE_) VALUES (204, 114, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ, ID_SELLER, DATE_) VALUES (205, 115, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ, ID_SELLER, DATE_) VALUES (206, 116, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ, ID_SELLER, DATE_) VALUES (207, 117, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ, ID_SELLER, DATE_) VALUES (208, 118, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ, ID_SELLER, DATE_) VALUES (209, 119, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Zakaz_(ID_ZAKAZ, ID_SELLER, DATE_) VALUES (210, 112, GETDATE());
```

See the way I used the same IDs in the ID_SELLER values (111, 112, ...) in both tables so I could make a relationship between them.

See the results:

```
SELECT * FROM Seller_;

ID_SELLER   PASS     FIO                            ADRESS
----------- -------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
111         abcd1    Anton                          derevnya universiady
112         abcd2    Andrey                         pushkina
113         abcd3    Abdul                          krasnaya pozitsiya
114         abcd1    Alsu                           derevnya universiady
115         abcd2    Anna                           pushkina
116         abcd3    Azamat                         krasnaya pozitsiya
117         abcd2    Sergei                         pushkina
118         abcd1    Leysan                         derevnya universiady
119         abcd1    Katya                          derevnya universiady
120         abcd3    Anastasia                      krasnaya pozitsiya

SELECT * FROM Zakaz_;

ID_ZAKAZ    DATE_      ID_SELLER
----------- ---------- -----------
201         2019-12-19 111
202         2019-12-19 112
203         2019-12-19 113
204         2019-12-19 114
205         2019-12-19 115
206         2019-12-19 116
207         2019-12-19 117
208         2019-12-19 118
209         2019-12-19 119
210         2019-12-19 112
```

You can even join the tables now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Seller_ s
INNER JOIN Zakaz_ z
    on s.ID_SELLER = z.ID_SELLER;

ID_SELLER   PASS     FIO                            ADRESS                         ID_ZAKAZ    DATE_      ID_SELLER
----------- -------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------- ---------- -----------
111         abcd1    Anton                          derevnya universiady           201         2019-12-19 111
112         abcd2    Andrey                         pushkina                       202         2019-12-19 112
113         abcd3    Abdul                          krasnaya pozitsiya             203         2019-12-19 113
114         abcd1    Alsu                           derevnya universiady           204         2019-12-19 114
115         abcd2    Anna                           pushkina                       205         2019-12-19 115
116         abcd3    Azamat                         krasnaya pozitsiya             206         2019-12-19 116
117         abcd2    Sergei                         pushkina                       207         2019-12-19 117
118         abcd1    Leysan                         derevnya universiady           208         2019-12-19 118
119         abcd1    Katya                          derevnya universiady           209         2019-12-19 119
112         abcd2    Andrey                         pushkina                       210         2019-12-19 112
```